# Transposed stem in MATLAB with matlab2tikz

Tags: matlab, view, plot, latex, transpose

I have got a little problem regarding matlab2tikz and maybe you are so kind to help me:

I have a stem-plot in matlab and I want to transpose the plot, so that the stems are no longer perpendicular to the x-axis, but perpendicular regarding the y-axis.
I know that this can be done for the stem-plot by simply typing in:

```
figure(1)
x = 0 : 10; y = x.^2;
stem(x,y)
view(90,-90)
```

But now here comes the problem:
If I invoke matlab2tikz like

```
matlab2tikz( 'myfile.tikz');
```

and include the graphic into LaTeX, the command view(90,-90) has been ignored.

Has anyone a solution for that?

PS.: Rotating afterwards in LaTeX is not alowed, because the stem-plot is originally a subplot.

Kind regards,
Tik0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by mimicing the stem- with a line plot:

```
figure(1)
x = 0 : 10;
y = x.^2;
hold on;
for idx = 1 : numel(x)
    line([0 y(idx)],[x(idx) x(idx)]);
    line([y(idx) y(idx)],[x(idx) x(idx)],'Marker','o','LineStyle','none');
end
```

Now everything works fine, even with matlab2tikz.

But maybe you have a better solution than that?